# How to insert a <CR> (Carriage Return) in a Javascript String?

Tags: javascript, string, notepad++, carriage-return

I need to insert a Carriage Return in a String. As far as I know the `\r` should do it but here is the problem:

I wrote this in the browser console: `1\r2` then I get: `12` in return. Now I copy/paste it on Notepad++ https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3AQO.jpg

There is a CR and a LF there. How I can add just a CR?

Note that you can replace the LF(\n) in notepad, save the file and the LFs are gone.

Comment: Why do you want this?

Comment: Probably Notepad++ added an LF by itself.

Comment: i make a CSV file and send it via Email, the line delimiters must be <CR> only.

Comment: Do you know you can change the line delimiter to CR only in notepad++? Menu **Edit - EOL Conversion - Old Mac Format**.

Comment: Yes, but that does not modify the file, just the way that you look at it in notepad++

Answer (score 5):

In ES6 with string templates you just introduce the carriage return as written text. 
Also you can use `\n` to mark carriage return in quoted strings.

```js
const str = `l
e`;

console.log(str);

const str2 = 'l\ne';

console.log(str2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually, carriage returns often go like this...

```
\n
```

and you can use more than one to go down multiple lines.

It's the equivalent of pressing the enter/return key after you type one line and you want to move to the next one.

For example,

```
var astring = "This is a \n test";

print(astring);
```

You would get:

```
This is a
test
```

Hope it answers your question,

Alexander B.