# Insert new line in contenteditable on Ctrl+Enter

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, carriage-return

I would like to insert a new line in a contenteditable when the user press Ctrl+Enter.

Based on the following questions, I wrote the code below:

- [Insert newline on enter key in contenteditable div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23974533/insert-newline-on-enter-key-in-contenteditable-div)
- [How to insert a <CR> (Carriage Return) in a Javascript String?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46673608/how-to-insert-a-cr-carriage-return-in-a-javascript-string/46673642)
- [Dealing with line Breaks on contentEditable DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6023307/dealing-with-line-breaks-on-contenteditable-div)
- [Problem detecting Newlines in JavaScript Range Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1146730/problem-detecting-newlines-in-javascript-range-object)

Here is my HTML:

```
<span id="myInput" contenteditable="true" style="white-space: pre;"></span>
```

Here is the JavaScript:

```
let myInput = document.getElementById('myInput');

myInput.addEventListener('keypress', (event) => {
    if (event.key == 'Enter' && event.ctrlKey == true) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.insertNewLine();     
   }
})


function insertNewLine(text) {

    var sel, range, html;
  sel = window.getSelection();
  range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
  range.deleteContents();
    
  // Do not always works
  var textNode = document.createTextNode("\n");
  
  // Always works
  //var textNode = document.createTextNode("\n\u200b");
    
  range.insertNode(textNode);
  range.setStartAfter(textNode);
  range.collapse(false);
  sel.removeAllRanges();
  sel.addRange(range);
}
```

When the user press Ctrl+Enter, the behavior is a bit weird:

- On Chrome, the new line is not always inserted
- On Firefox, the new line is inserted, but the caret does not jump to the next line

I noticed that the above code always works when an zero-width space (`\u200b`) is added after the `\n` character.

I made a JSFidle: https://jsfiddle.net/Alphonsio/atr7e2uw/27/

Of course, I'd prefer not to insert the second character. But I can't figure out why the new line is not inserted in the first case (`\n` only). Can anyone help?

Comment: I would suggest that what you are doing is wrong. Spans should not contain new lines. In fact nothing in HTML should have new line characters like that - <BR> is the tag you want

Comment: @ControlAltDel I didn't mention it, but the contenteditable have the `white-space: pre;` property. It's in the JsFiddle. I updated the question

Answer (score 0):

ive looked into your problem a bit

```js
//js

        set(6);
        myInput.focus();
        
        myInput.onkeyup   = e=>{
        
                if(!(e.key=='Enter'&&e.ctrlKey))return;
            
              e.preventDefault();
              
              var pos               = get();
              
              var str               = myInput.textContent;
              var newstr            = str.slice(0,pos)+'\n'+str.slice(pos);
              myInput.textContent   = newstr;
              
              set(pos+1);
              
        }//onkeyup
        
        function get(){
          
              return window.getSelection().focusOffset;
              
        }//get
        
        function set(pos){
          
              var txt               = myInput.firstChild;
              var range             = document.createRange()
              range.setStart(txt,0);
              range.setEnd(txt,pos);
              range.collapse(false);
              
              var selection         = window.getSelection();
              selection.removeAllRanges();
              selection.addRange(range);
              
        }//set
```

```css
        
/*css*/
        
        #myInput {
              display       : block;
              border        : 1px solid black;
              padding       : 5px;
              width         : 300px;
              height        : 200px;
              white-space   : pre;
        }
```

```html
<!--html-->            
        
        <p>Type some characters and press Ctrl+Enter</p>
        
        <span id=myInput contenteditable=true>12345678</span>
```

i use chrome mainly, it all works

except when the cursor is at the end of the string, then the newline **is** inserted at the end but the browser doesnt seem to pick it up in the ui, seems to be a browser bug, ive tried it with various elements and all are the same

ive just noticed, if you delete a character it starts working, try playing around with it

if you chose to use a `textarea`, then it does work and you can just use

```
    var pos                 = myInput.selectionEnd;
    var str                 = myInput.value;
    myInput.value           = str.slice(0,pos)+'\n'+str.slice(pos);
    myInput.selectionEnd    = pos+1;
```

now i come to think about it, browsers have always been a bit funny about white space at the end of contents, even with white-space set to `pre`, they just love to collapse whitespace

its fine to use newlines in any element in html, theyre a fundamental part of the html specification, a span is just an inline element

you use a span and then set its display to be block, which effectively renders it as a div as far as i can tell

i'll post this for now so i dont lose my edits, i do have some more to suggest on the subject ...

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Of course, I have a good reason to use contenteditable instead of textarea. I also start thinking this is a bug. Therefore, I noticed that when you press Enter, the browser sometime add two \n (at the end of line for example), and sometime only one.

Comment: @Alphonsio, i think i have a working solution, im just ironing out the details, im interested in this stuff myself, may i ask your reason for using contenteditable instead of a textarea, a textarea can be styled anyway you want, off the top of my head the only differences would be a textarea is a replacedelement therefore has intrinsic width and height which if not set will override other css values, also a textarea would not be able to contain other elements, anyway im not far off finishing a working solution to this

Comment: i'm using a CSS ::before property on the contenteditable. This property can't be apply to `textarea`

Answer (score -1):

Use < BR /> instead of \n

```js
document.querySelector("button").addEventListener("click", function() {
  let s = document.querySelector("span");
  console.log("text: " + s.innerHTML);
  //s.textContent = "<br/>" + s.textContent;
  s.innerHTML = "<br/>" + s.innerHTML;
});
```

```css
span {
  contenteditable: true;
  whitespace: pre;
}
```

```html
<button>Click me</button>
<p contenteditable=false>ZZZ
<span contenteditable=true>ABC</span>
</p>
```

Comment: The problem is the same with <br>, I already try.